# How to solve the error "com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.get()' on a null object reference"

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

[I have tried all the way to solve the .get error but I don't get any solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfptK.jpg)

TextView detailLength = view.findViewById(R.id.detailLength);
TextView detailShoulder = view.findViewById(R.id.detailShoulder);

```
    db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    DocumentReference measurementdata = db.collection("measurement").getParent();
    measurementdata.get()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
            MeasurementAdapter measurementAdapter = documentSnapshot.toObject(MeasurementAdapter.class);

            String length = measurementAdapter.getLength();

            String shoulder = measurementAdapter.getShoulder();


            detailLength.setText(length);
```

//                detailShoulder.setText(shoulder);
}

```
    });
```

I have tried this code but the text did not set in TextView.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the `NullPointerException` because of the following line of code:

```
DocumentReference measurementdata = db.collection("measurement").getParent();
```

When you're calling [CollectionReference#getParent()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/CollectionReference#getParent()) on a top-level collection, according to the docs:

> Gets a `DocumentReference` to the document that contains this collection. Only subcollections are contained in a document. **For root collections, returns `null`**.

To avoid that, you have to remove the call to `.getParent()` and add a call to [CollectionReference#document()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/CollectionReference#document()) to create a [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentReference) object. And to make it work, don't forget to pass the ID of the document you want to read.

Comment: Hey Bhadra. Have you tried my solution above, does it work for you?